# "Save As" box in a pdf file

Tags: pdf, save-as

Please help.
Is it possible to create in pdf file a button which brings up the "Save As" box for saving a linked file?
I have used **Forms** feature in Adobe Acrobat 2017 but without any results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link from adobe to create a button in pdf  [Setting action buttons in PDF forms](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/setting-action-buttons-pdf-forms.html)

Comment: Hi Rebwar,
for buttons there is action **Open a file**. But in case if no any program associated with certain file I have an error message from Adobe: No program associated with this file... That's why I need the "Save As" box instead of "Open a file" function.

Maybe it is possible with **Run JavaScript** action, but I'm illiterate in programming. Please advice.

Comment: I think your solution is wrong, you can use the online form to save information like google forms or you should write some codes for yourself

Comment: Everything should be offline. Thanks for respond.

Comment: but where these files to be saved?

Comment: Everything should be on storage device (hdd, ssd). I want to give to user the opportunity to save some source file from pdf instruction.

Comment: can you share the sample(or image of that you want)?

Comment: Here is two files

**doc01.pdf** and 
**0302_CE_mark.frw**

pdf-file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1epg1G9PVFrWVQW5SvRT3VWRsot0G0J0H
attached file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TfcyV5CcEh_jhme_CJ1iNrt3rnNTn0Yc

In case if you don't have a program associated with *.frw file you will get an error message from Adobe: No program associated with this file...
I using Adobe Reader XI for viewing pdf.